# How to resolve Titanium TableView display problem?

Tags: titanium, tableview

I have tableview in titanium.I have displayed 12 labels in 3 different rows.When i am using it first time it is showing all of the 3 rows properly with content.

Whenever i am coming back from the tableview to other view and again i am going to access the same tableview, i can not see tableview content, i can only see blank rows.

can anybody help me out , what exactly the problem is and why am i not able to see content again(2nd time) when tableview loads.

I have added whole code snippet below :

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

var atmData =[];
var tableView;

var titledata =[
    'Member No:',
    'A/C Type:',
    'A/C Desc:',
    'A/C: ',
    'State:',
    'Zip:',
    'Surcharge\nAmount:',
];

var Value =[
    '28956',
    'Savings',
    '85416',
    '025489',
    'California',
    '38847',
    'Free',
];

var FirstLabel =[];
var FirstText = [];
var SecondLabel =[];
var SecondText = [];
var ThirdLabel =[];
var ThirdText = [];
var FourthLabel =[];
var FourthText = [];
var FifthLabel =[];
var FifthText = [];
var SixthLabel =[];
var SixthText = [];


for (var i=0; i < 3; i++){  

    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
    //row.backgroundColor = '#576996';
    row.selectedBackgroundColor = '#385292';
    //row.height = 170; 
    FirstLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Member No:',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{fontSize:13,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width: 110,
    left:10,
    height:20,
    top :0
});

FirstText = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'35687',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{
        fontSize:13,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width:'auto',
    height:20,
    left:120,
    top :0
});

SecondLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'A/C Type:',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{fontSize:13,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width: 100,
    height:20,
    left:10,
    top :25
});

SecondText = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Savings',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{
        fontSize:13,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width:'auto',
    height:20,
    left:120,
    top :25
});

ThirdLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'A/C Desc:',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{fontSize:13,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width: 100,
    height:20,
    left:10,
    top :50
});

ThirdText= Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'65565616',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{
        fontSize:13,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width:'auto',
    height:20,
    left:120,
    top :50
});

FourthLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'A/C:',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{fontSize:13,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width: 100,
    height:20,
    left:10,
    top :75
});

FourthText= Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'861556.00',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{
        fontSize:13,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width:'auto',
    height:20,
    left:120,
    top :75
});

FifthLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'ZIP :',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{fontSize:13,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width: 100,
    height:20,
    left:10,
    top :100
});

FifthText= Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'388546',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{
        fontSize:13,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width:'auto',
    height:20,
    left:120,
    top :100
});

SixthLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Surcharge\nAmount:',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{fontSize:13,
          fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width: 100,
    height:50,
    left:10,
    top :125
});

SixthText= Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Free',
    color:'black',
    //textAlign:'left',
    //font:{fontSize:13,fontWeight:'bold'},
    font:{
        fontSize:12,
        fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'
    },
    width:'auto',
    height:50,
    left:120,
    top :125
});

row.className = 'header';

row.add(FirstLabel);
row.add(FirstText);
row.add(SecondLabel);
row.add(SecondText);
row.add(ThirdLabel);
row.add(ThirdText);
row.add(FourthLabel);
row.add(FourthText);
row.add(FifthLabel);
row.add(FifthText);
row.add(SixthLabel);
row.add(SixthText);
atmData.push(row);

backgroundColor:'transparent'   
};

var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:atmData,
    rowHeight:170,
});

win.add(tableview);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar problem that I was able to fix by putting `tableview.setData(tableview.data);` into any events that caused the table to look strange.